# Blackberry OS 5,6,7

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I have to build a app that should support Blackberry OS 5,6,7. My question is would one app would be enough or do I have to build 2 separate apps?
i.e 1 compatible with OS 5 and 2nd with OS 6 and 7.

Also I would like to know if there are any open source graph API's for Blackberry 5,6,7 or not!

Please guide me!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by open source graph API's?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "graphing" APIs?

Answer (score 1):

You may build for 5, 6 and 7 at one time. Use pre-processor directives to avoid compilation problems for multiple OS's. Then you would need to check separately for UI items depending upon the screen resolution and OS version. One quick check can be `Display.getWidth()`.